System to roll up outdoor blinds that came without cords
I got some outdoor blinds to shade my balcony, specifically these. They apparently no longer sell the kind with a cord system to roll them up, instead they have these obnoxious little clips. I belatedly realized that I installed the shades so high up that I need a stepladder to roll them up or down, which is obviously annoying.
I'd like to build some sort of cord system to do this. I'm vaguely thinking of adding pulleys on the hooks that are already supporting the blinds, and wrapping cord around the bottom bar. That seems like it might work well enough, but still be a bit awkward and impractical. Is there a better solution for this, or something already designed out?

I believe the cords were removed/banned since young children were hanging themselves on them.

@crip659 I get that impression as well. But there won't be any young children in my apartment, so I'm not overly concerned about that.

If no young children ever, then @triplefaults improvement will work better.

@crip indoors, looped cords were the main issue there, especially unrestrained ones.  Some manufacturers went for cord restraints or wands, others (e.g. ikea) stopped making blinds that work in favour of spring-loaded things that only latch hen they feel like it

The Home Depot site is giving me an ‘Access Denied’ error.  Is it the same blind shown on Amazon, Walmart, and Bed Bath & Beyond?

@gidds weird, but yes it's the same shade

Would need three pulleys, a short and long cord and a hook/boat thingy/holder to hold the cord.
Attach the long cord to the short cord before pulley B.  Pulley A will be at the far end of the blinds, so long cord goes to the bottom.  Pulley B is at the near end, and pulley C is on the wall, so the cord will go down to the cord holder.
It is bad I know, but hope you can make sense of it. I will not give up my day job to become an artist.



crip's idea is where I was going to post on seeing the question, except the ropes need to go under and up the other side. I added a side view to show where the ropes needed to continue. If the ropes don't go around and up, the blinds will be pulled only at the bottom and will fold up to half height maximum. (we had a set of these blinds with the rope & pulley setup once.)

@Triplefault   That will work better, but OP will have to check local regulations about cord/rope loops on blinds.  Many blinds with cord loops have been recalled.

Yeah, this is roughly what I was thinking as well. I'm not clear how the knot would work though, I'd think it would get pulled over pulley C when rolling up the blinds, which would be problematic. I'm not really sure of a better way to handle this though, short of having Pulley C be a stack of pulleys or something like that.

@BrianReischl  If using poly cord/rope, unwrapping and twisting around, plus some heat should bind the two cords together.  If using knots, they should be small enough to go though the pulleys, or can use a short sheave.

I prototyped this out with some nylon cord and a crappy keychain carabiner I had sitting around, it actually works surprisingly well. One problem is that you need to pull a lot of cord through to roll it all the way up - it's effectively a 2-to-1 hauling system, so you pull cord length equal to 2x the height of the blind. So you can't really put any permanent knot or anything in the cord, you really do need either a cleat (as you mentioned in the post) or a handy railing and proficiency with knots.
I'm going to get some more rope and try to actually build it, will report back.

I had a set of wide blinds that worked exactly this way. It was actually a single rope loop ; lemme see if I can draw that... Actually, I think I can get a photo of something similar.

I recommend braided cord (like sash cord) to avoid issues with twisting.  With a heavy blind you may need actual pulleys and not just running the cord through screw eyes

You can avoid the knots by running separate cords. Ceiling-mounted clothes airers do this, and could be a source of inspiration and even parts

Question: how would this make the blind actually roll up when you pull the cord, instead of simply bunching?

@Huesmann in practice it seems to work, though it's probably not reliable. If the blind is already a little bit rolled up it'll just sort of "follow along", but if it was full extension it might not. May also depend on the kind of cord used - my guess is slippery cord probably works better.

I actually did build the accepted answer, I am just posting this so I can add some color and notes. But it's the same basic design.
I used 1/8" braided nylon cord, largely because I already had some and there was enough handy at the hardware store. Also the white color blends into the sky a bit better, though it stands out against the blinds. It certainly overkill for the application, as the strength of a single strand is more than the entire weight of the blind.
Where the diagram specifies "pulleys", I opted to use simple steel rings. They're about a quarter the price, and also make it easy to run multiple cords through them in slightly different directions, which is handy since the blinds actually use three hangers and hence I used three cords.


I didn't feel like measuring out and cords to cut them (though it ends up being about 20-24' each, depending which end of the blind you're connecting to), and the blinds were already hung and kind of a PITA to take down, so I ran the cord through "in reverse" and then tied them to the anchors behind the blind. This was a little ticklish, since I don't have easy access to the back, but worked OK.
Using a cleat to tie up the ropes would be ideal, but it's also a pain for me to add hardware in this spot. I do have a balcony railing handy though, so I used that for now.
I've tried a few wraps around the railing and then a slip knot carabinered to the line to keep it from coming out.

And also a mule hitch with an overhand backup.

Both work reasonably well, though it may be a little more rope work than your average person would want to do just to roll up the blinds. I may do something better at some point.
I also found that the stupid thing flops around in the breeze a lot, which I should've expected. I've temporarily addressed that by creating cord loops around the railing uprights (actually old shoelace tied with a double fisherman's) and using the stupid clips supplied with the blind to attach the bottom of the blind to them. This seems to work better than I expected, and is certainly good enough for now.
